# How to Save reactjs state object in LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I want to save the state of movies in localstorage. I am stuck and have no idea on how to implement this. I tried to add `localStorage.setItem('movies', JSON.stringify(this.state.movies))` in the addMovie method in the App component but this did not work. I have listed my App component and my CreateMovieForm component below.

This website stores movies in a list.
The way this website works is that it has a movies state in the app component. All the components do is manipulate this movies state. It does not matter if they delete or add a movie. The state always gets updated and the list of movies gets re-rendered.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      movies: []
    }
  }

  addMovie(movie) {
    this.setState({
      movies: this.state.movies.concat(movie)
    })
    console.log(this.state.movies);
  }

  createDeltedList(newMovies){
    this.setState({
      movies: newMovies
    })
  }

  sortMovies(){
    let movies = this.state.movies;
    movies.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.grade - a.grade;
    })
    this.setState({movies: movies})
  }

  sortMoviesAlpha(){
    let movies = this.state.movies;
    movies.sort(function(a, b) {
      if (a.title > b.title){
        return 1
      }
      if (a.title < b.title){
        return -1
      }
      return 0
    })
    this.setState({movies: movies})
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <AppTitle attr='display-4' title='Min film lista ' />
        <LeadText attr='lead' text='Lägg till film:' />
        <AddLine />
        <CreateMovieForm addMovie={this.addMovie.bind(this)} attr='form-group' from='form-control' btnSave='Spara film'/>
        <SortGradeButton sortMovies={this.sortMovies.bind(this)} text='Sort by Grade'/>
        <SortAlphaButton sortMoviesAlpha={this.sortMoviesAlpha.bind(this)} text='Sort Alphabetically' />
        <MovieList genNewList={this.createDeltedList.bind(this)} movies={this.state.movies} />
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

```
class CreateMovieForm extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {title: '', grade: '1'};

    this.handleTitleChange = this.handleTitleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleGradeChange = this.handleGradeChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSave = this.handleSave.bind(this);
  }
  handleTitleChange(event) {
    this.setState({title: event.target.value});
  }

  handleGradeChange(event){
    this.setState({grade: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSave(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let movie = {
      title: this.state.title,
      grade: this.state.grade
    }
    this.props.addMovie(movie)   
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSave}>
        <div className={this.props.attr}>
          <label htmlFor='movieTitle'>Titel:</label>
          <input type='text' className={this.props.from} placeholder='Titel här...' title={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleTitleChange}/>
        </div>
        <div className={this.props.attr}>
          <label htmlFor='grade'>Betyg:</label>
          <select id='grade' className={this.props.from} grade={this.state.grade} onChange={this.handleGradeChange}>
              <option>Välj betyg här...</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <button className='btn btn-info'>{this.props.btnSave} </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please define "did not work".

Answer (score 0):

You can acccess the window.localStorage method

By setting data to the localStorage localStorage.setItem('key', value );

And also getting  localStorage.getItem('key', value);

You can also save an array by passing data

// let’s say am saving an array of books with objects values 
localStorage.setItem('books',JSON.stringify(books));

let books = localStorage.getItem('books');
books = JSON.parse(books);
I hope this helps